# Remove the column Quantity from email notifications in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, email-notifications

In Woocommerce, I would like remove the column Quantity from email notifications like in the screenshot below:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

> This can be done [Overriding the following WooCommerce Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

**The related template**s are `email/email-order-items.php` and `emails/email-order-details.php`.

Once you have copied this template to `yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php` and also `yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php` open edit it them:

1) For the template `email/email-order-items.php`:

- **Change** on line 78 `<td colspan="3"` to `<td colspan="2"`
- **Remove** the following code block from line 66 to 68:

  ```
  <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
  <?php echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', $item->get_quantity(), $item ) ); ?>
  ```

2) For the template `email/email-order-details.php`:

- **Change** on line 70 `<th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2"` to `<th class="td" scope="row"`
- **Change** on line 79 `<th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2"` to `<th class="td" scope="row"`
- **Remove** the code block from line 45:

  ```
  <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
  ```

Save both templates, you are done… You will get something like:

[image]